# Bash: Is there different on set locale through export other than update-locale?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, export, locale

I found that there is two ways to set locale in Ubuntu.

One is through export:

```
export LANG=en_US.utf-8
```

And another one is through update-locale:

```
update-locale en_US.utf-8
```

Are there any significant different on setting locale?

If yes, what is the properly way to set locale in Ubuntu as well as CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update-locale en_US.utf-8
```

would modify global locale settings.

```
export LANG=en_US.utf-8
```

would modify it only for the current shell.

Comment: if i add the export command inside /etc/environment, so all shell will read the export command, then would there any different still?

Comment: That should work equally well.